# How to avoid Blank cells when using IF Formula in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]

I have a Table and in column D i will enter this formula.

```
=IF(AND(A2<=(TODAY()+90);C2<=40%);"High";"Low")
```

I will insert inside a Table. So it can be automatically draged down.
Based on conditions, it will show High or Low and then it will highlight only the entire row for "High". But my problem is if there is no values in Column C; then it is still showing as High and Highlighting. If there is no value then it should not show anything. How to change the formula. Help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add one more condition:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C2);"";IF(AND(A2<=(TODAY()+90);C2<=40%);"High";"Low"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are useing a Table inside A Table i would Work With @. and a Second if Condition.

```
=If([@Complete]="";"";IF(AND([@Date]<=(TODAY()+90);@Complete<=40%);"High";"Low")
```